# Storing detailed data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I’m designing a database in which I save votes.
I’ve created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users_votes](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [like_votes] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [dislike_votes] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [commented_votes] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [comments_likes] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
```

The issue is that there is a requirement to also store the breakdown data by location.
So for example if `user_votes` table has 1,000 `like_votes` for a specific id, I need to know the break down by location, e.g.:

> United States 340
>
> France 155
>
> Denmark 25
>
> Brazil 290
>
> Australia 190

I’m getting the data from the client as comma delimited String, for example:
(1,2,45,67,87,112,234) and the country code for location (us, au, ca, etc...).

I’ve been thinking about a few possibilities to store this data, but wanted to know which of these approached is best suited (if any).

1. As the number of country codes is finite, I can expand `users_votes` table and add columns with country codes for each criteria. E.g. `like_votes_us, dislike_votes_us, comment_votes_us, comment_likes_us.`
   In this case I will probably use Dynamic SQL to insert/update the data.
2. Create new tables for each column, so for example I will have a table named `like_votes`, in which I will have an `id, external_id` which will be users_votes (table) id, `country_code`, and `count` column. So the data will be stored in `users_votes` and also in `like_votes` table. I will have a record for each combination of `external_id` and `country code`.
   In this case I will need to iterate the inserted data in order to determine if this external_id combination exists (and then just increment it) or it needs to be inserted.

Which approach, if any, is the optimal way to store this data so it will be easy to insert/update and also to query?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, are you storing aggregate values in your table? Why? That's a bad idea to start with, considering what your goal is. Have you considered using Normal Form?

Comment: Are you referring to users_votes table? If so, then yes.

Comment: That is the only table you have at the moment. :) Well, if that's the case, it seems, honestly, that your design is flawed at the off set. Give me a bit of time to post something that'll help you get off to a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of table design you have at the moment isn't a good idea, in all honesty. One big important point of building a good relational database is using Normal Form. i'm not going to explain what that is here, as there are 10's of thousands of articles on the internet explaining it, and its different iterations (from 1NF to 6NF iirc).

Anyway, you can easily do this with a few tables. I having to guess a lot of your set up here, but hopefully you'll be able to extrapolate what you need, and adjust what doesn't.

Firstly, let's start with a client table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Client (ClientID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                         ClientName varchar(100), --You should really split this into Title, Forename and Surname, I'm just being "lazy" here
                         ClientCountryID int, --Not sure if a Client is related to a country or the vote is, i've guessed the client is.
                         DOB date,
                         EmailAddress varchar(100));
GO
```

So, we have a simple Client Table now. Next, we want a Country Table. This is very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Country (CountryID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                          CountryName varchar(100),
                          CountryCode char(2)); --For example UK for United Kingdom, FR for France, etc
GO
```

You might want to store additional content there, but I don't know your set up.

Now, this is where I'm really guessing a lot. I'm **assuming** that your likes and dislikes, etc, are linked to something. What, I have no idea, so, I'm going to have a table called "Content", however, not knowing what these likes are against, I have no context for this table, thus it's going to be very basic:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Content (ContentID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                          ContentType int, --Guessing might be types, maybe videos, Comments, articles? I have no idea to be honest)
                          ContentParent int, --Comments are joined to a Content (just like here on SO)? I'll guess it's possible
                          Content nvarchar(MAX)); --because I have no idea what's going in there

--Very simple Content Type Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.ContentType (TypeID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                              TypeDescription varchar(100));
GO
```

Now, finally, we can get onto the votes that you want to store; which might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vote (VoteID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                       ClientID int,
                       ContentID int,
                       Liked bit); --1 for Liked, 0 for Disliked, NULL for N/A perhaps?
GO
```

Ok, now we have some tables. Now I realise I haven't given any kind of Sample data to go in here, so I'll provide a few INSERTS statements for you, so you can get the idea:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Country (CountryName, CountryCode)
VALUES ('United Kingdom','GB'),
       ('France','FR'),
       ('Germany','DE');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Client (ClientName, ClientCountryID, DOB, EmailAddress)
VALUES ('Mr John Smith',1, '19880106','Bob@gmial.com'),
       ('Ms Penelope Vert',2,'19930509','PVert@mfn.com');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.ContentType (TypeDescription)
VALUES ('Video'),('Article'),('Comment');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Content (ContentType, ContentParent, Content)
VALUES (2, NULL, 'This is my first article, hi everyone!'),
       (3, 1, 'Nice! Good to see you''re finally posting!'),
       (1, NULL, 'http://youtube.com');
GO

--And now some votes:
INSERT INTO dbo.Vote (ClientID, ContentID, Liked)
VALUES (1, 1, 1),
       (2, 1, 1),
       (2, 2, 1),
       (2, 3, 0);
GO
```

Notice how I've put the votes in. I've not aggregated in the table; doing so is an awful idea. instead store each vote individually and use a query to Aggregate. You can easily do this, for example:

```
SELECT C.ContentID,
       Cy.CountryName,
       COUNT(CASE V.Liked WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS LikedVotes,
       COUNT(CASE V.Liked WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS DisLikedVotes
FROM dbo.Content C
     JOIN dbo.Vote V ON C.ContentID = V.ContentID
     JOIN dbo.Client CV ON V.ClientID = CV.ClientID
     JOIN dbo.Country Cy ON CV.ClientCountryID = Cy.CountryID
GROUP BY C.ContentID,
         Cy.CountryName;
```

This gives you the number of Liked Votes per Content Item, and splits it into Countries as well for you. If you want to put these countries into their own columns, then I **strongly** suggest doing this in your presentation layer, not your SQL (as you'll have to use Dynamic SQL, and (no offence) I imagine this is beyond your skills at the moment based on your current database design choice(s)). Excel is very good at going this using Pivot tables. if you want to retain the process in SQL Server, consider using SSRS and a matrix.

If you have any questions, please do ask.

*Note: I have no made any kind of foreign keys, constraints, Default values, etc here. These are a definate must for any good database design.*

*Clean Up script:*

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Client;
DROP TABLE dbo.Country;
DROP TABLE dbo.Vote;
DROP TABLE dbo.Content;
DROP TABLE dbo.ContentType;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting storing each vote in its own record? wouldn't it be huge?
If I have for example 50K items and 200K voting users then table size will be 50K X 200K?

Comment: @UdiIdan , yes, that is **exactly** what I am suggesting. Each row for the vote contains 3 x `int` and 1 x `bit`. An `int` is 4 bytes in size, and a `bit` is 1 byte. That's a total of 3 x 4 + 1 = 13 bytes per row. There is, also, an overhead (which i can't recall the size of, but i think it might be 4 Bytes), so that totals 17 Bytes. 1 Megabyte is 1048576 Bytes. So, in 1MB of data you can store about 61680 votes. That's a lot of votes for very little storage space. So, to answer you question "Wouldn't it be huge?": No, no it would not be.

Comment: I understand, but if I have 50K items and 200K votes, it's 50,000 X 200,000 = 10,000,000,000. If 1MB can store 61K votes, it's 10,000,000,000 / 61K = 163,934 MB. Taking into consideration that I don't need to know what each client voted, but just the aggregation by country, doesn't this design store too much data?

Comment: No, it really doesn't. Considering that you've already designed your table and then later discovered that you need to get the country of the voting person, what makes you think that isn't going to change in the long term? If you're really saying that you're storing 10 Billion votes, do you really think that that data the data is going to be "small"?

Comment: As a quick example, what happens if, in the future, you need to know the details of votes by the client's Gender? If you don't have a relationship between votes and clients, and just the aggregate table, how do you propose that you obtain that data? You might say "But they're not asking that", but that doesn't mean they won't. In my own experiences I have countless times where I've asked  and been told "no, we don't need that, and won't ever need it" to be asked, maybe year down the line "can we that?". Then they get really annoyed when I tell them no; because they said they'll never need it.

Comment: I completely understand your point of view, but I do need to balance the data needed to data that might be needed. The difference here is huge for data that they might or might not need. My assumption here is that user specific data is not needed.

Comment: This is 100% the correct approach even at the scale you are describing, which seems a bit far fetched to me. Do you actually expect each one of your 200k users to vote 50k times each? This would require every single user to vote 13 times per day, every day for 10 years! This equates to your system receiving 1902 votes per minute (30 per second) consistently for 10 years. If you have a client base this interactive then you need to hire a professional DBA to fix these problems for you ASAP.

Comment: @UdiIdan then your assumption is wrong. you've already stated you need the country the vote is from, which is client specific information. Thus, your post already disproves your assumption.

Comment: @GarethD The votes in the system are not always explicit, but actions the user make. A user can easily perform more than 100 actions a day. 
There are actually a lot more than 200K users, so I think it can reach those numbers.

Comment: @Larnu Although I understand what you're saying, I think that in this scenario there is a difference between having a record for a specific action for the entire US and having a record for each user in the US.
I will need to re-think this, as your comments are 100% valid and reasonable.  I do think, though, that the solution will have to be thinner.

Comment: @Larnu - The users are divided into 8 regions (which don't have any correlation between them). Do you think that creating 8 tables dbo.Vote_region_name is a good idea?

Comment: @UdiIdan , no, store the region alongside the vote. Otherwise you have 8 tables you have to `UNION` to get data for all regions.